# My laptop hangs frequently. How can I diagnose it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, windows-registry, freeze

So my laptop is Alienware M17XR3 with a few problems. The battery is dead and I haven't replaced it yet cause it's permanently on my desk plugged in to a  power outlet. The graphics card was Nvidia GTX 580m and it's also dead cause of overheating. I just use this laptop mainly for light gaming, watching videos and web browsing.

I think the problem begins after a few blackouts (quite common in my country) and without the battery, I can't shut it down properly. The hanging happens randomly when I'm web browsing, playing games or just on idle.

I was searching around the internet and saw that it might be problems with the hard drive or the registry so I downloaded Seatools for windows to check the hard drive and wise registry cleaner to check the registry. I also used Microsoft security essentials to check for viruses and malwarebytes anti rootkit for rootkits.

The hard drive passed the long generic test and I've defragmented it. I've completed registry cleanup and defrag and did the system tuneup. Microsoft security essentials found no viruses and malwarebytes found no rootkits.

After going through all the tests, it seems that my system is fine but there's definitely something wrong with it. Please help me find the problem. I'm hoping that the problem can be resolved without buying a new laptop cause this one is still somewhat usable.

Comment: press the CAPS Lock key during the freeze. does the light on the keyboard toggle or not? If yes, it is a software issue, if not you have hardware issues.

Comment: any update? if the issue fixed or not?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of updates. My laptop hasn't been hanging for a while so I thought it's all good now. However, it hanged again yesterday. I've pressed the caps lock button to check the lights and it didn't toggle. What diagnostic tools should I get to check my hardware integrity? Free ones preferably.

Comment: run memtest86+ to test RAM and prime95 to test the CPU: http://www.mersenne.org/download/

Comment: I've just completed memtest and there's no error detected. Just downloaded prime95. I'm unsure which test should I run and how long should I run it for?

Comment: So prime 95 is up and running right now. I've also downloaded realtemp to check the temperatures. It's a bit scary and weird right now. The temperatures in the cores are maxed at 96 degrees and 74 degrees at minimum. These temperatures are reported in matter of seconds to one another and I don't think 20 degrees celcius fluctuations in seconds are possible. Should I keep running prime 95?

Comment: ok, so the heat seams to be the issue. Try to carefully clean the CPU cooler from dust

Comment: Well...My laptop seems to have completed prime 95 for 8 hours without issue. Even though the temperature stayed around 90 degrees all the time. I'll still try cleaning the cooler though.

Comment: So I cleaned out the cooler and used real temp to check the temperatures periodically and found that it peaked at 81 degrees C since the CPU isn't being pushed to the limits in my normal daily use. However, yesterday when I was using my laptop normally, it hanged again, this time when I was watching a youtube video. What I noticed was that the video slowed down to about half speed even though I didn't touch anything. A few seconds after that I was still able to move my mouse and toggle the CAPSLOCK light and then it hanged like usual.

Comment: does this only happen when you watch youtube videos? if yes, try to disable HW acceleration in flash options

Comment: This is the first time I noticed the slowdown before a hang. As for the hanging itself, it happens randomly. When the system is idle, during a gaming session, web browsing, watching youtube videos and watching a downloaded video on the system itself. I used windows media player classic if that helps. One thing I am unsure about is the video driver. As my GPU is fried, I took it out myself to continue using the laptop with the integrated graphics. However, I have yet to clean my system of the previously installed drivers from Nvidia. Could this be a possible cause of the hanging?

Answer (score 0):

Your troubleshooting steps seem sound so far.

- Apart from checking the Windows system files integrity (On CMD as Admin run `sfc /scannow`) and testing the RAM with Memtest:
- My recommendation is to try a different/alternative OS (ie. installed on a separate/blank/new hard disk drive).

This way you'll be able to tell if your issue is "Hardware" or "Software".